# Core Resource Checking Permission make Server/Site Down afterwards

Tags: magento-1.9, error, sql, server-setup

[image]

I am running website on Magento 1.9.2.4 When I access my site and check query in mysql `SHOW PROCESSLIST` I get `state of "core_resource" table like Checking Permission`. Also it shows `State like Opening Tables`

Notice, after this whole site get slow and within few minutes server goes down.

I tried every time and it happens all time.

I made some R&D about it but did not get any suitable solution.

```
Is this a default message for Magento Platform websites?
Why server/site is getting down after this log?
Why Core resource table is all time showing state as opening table and checking permission?
```

My Server configuration: 64GB RAM/1.44 TB Hard Disk with Cent OS 6.8 OS

Any suggestion is appreciated.